# Error in pagination if there are no records

Tags: php, mysql

the script here works ok expect if there are no records in database i receive the following error on the page

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-5' at line 1

and here is the php and mysql part

```
     try {

    require_once 'db.php';
    $total = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM article')->fetchColumn();    

    $per_page = 5;


    $pages = ceil($total / $per_page);

    $page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(

        'options' => array(

            'default'   => 1,

            'min_range' => 1,

        ),

    )));


    $offset = ($page - 1)  * $per_page;
    $start = $offset + 1;
    $end = min(($offset + $per_page), $total);


   $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY ne_title LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset');


    $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();    

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $iterator = new IteratorIterator($stmt);

        foreach ($iterator as $row) {

                $desc = $row["ne_article"];

                $img = $row['ne_image'];

                if(!empty($img)){

                $img = '<br/><img src="uploads/images/'.$img.'" alt="" class="responsive-shrink">';

                }else{

                $img = '';

                }

                $youtube = $row["ne_youtube"];    

                if(!empty($youtube)){

                $youtube = '<br/><div class="video-container"><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$youtube.'"></iframe></div>';

                }else{

                $youtube = '';

                }

        echo '<h4><a href="'.$row['ne_url'].'">'.$row['ne_title'].'</a></h4>

                <h5><b>Views:</b> '.$row['views'].', <b>Posted on:</b> '.format_date($row['created']).'</h5>                

                '.$img.'

                '.$youtube.'

                <p>

                <br/>'.bbcode(nl2br(shortenString($desc))).'

                </p>

                 <div id="pagelink">

                <a href="'.$row['ne_url'].'" class="myButton"> Read more...</button></a>

                    </div>';        

        }

    echo '<div id="pagination">
    <div id="pagiCount">';
        $prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<span id="prev"><a href="?page=1" title="First page">First</a></span> <span id="prev"><a href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '" title="Previous page"><<</a></span>' : '';
        $nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<span id="next"><a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '" title="Next page">>></a></span> <span id="next"><a href="?page=' . $pages . '" title="Last page">Last</a></span>' : '';
        echo '<div id="paging"><p><small>', $prevlink, ' Page ', $page, ' of ', $pages, '', $nextlink, '</small></p></div>';       

    echo '</div></div>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>No resilts found.</p>';

    }

} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo '<p>', $e->getMessage(), '</p>';

}
```

could someone help fix this?

Comment: Make sure `limit` and `offset` is not negativ

Comment: how to do that? would appreciate your help

Comment: if your `$page` variable is 0, then your `$offset` value would be negative

Comment: so how do i fix it if there is no record in database page value would become 0 wont it?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're over complicating things. Try something like this, notice that I've bound $start and $end instead of your $limit variable. Start will never be negative or zero because of your other code...

```
$total = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM article')->fetchColumn();    
$per_page = 5;

$pages = ceil($total / $per_page); // total number of pages

$offset = ($page - 1)  * $per_page;
$start = $offset + 1;
$end = min(($offset + $per_page), $total);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY ne_title LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset');

$stmt->bindParam(':limit', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':offset', $end, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: i get no results found doing so if i add record to database

Comment: anyone could fix this?